# Form created with React doesn't update the backing state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to automate the login form of Instagram web app:

https://instagram.com/accounts/login/

With the following code (you can run it on Chrome console):

```
var frm = window.frames[1].document.forms[0];
frm.elements[0].value = 'qacitester';
frm.elements[1].value = 'qatester';
frm.elements[2].click();
```

Even though the inputs are populated, when I monitor the XHR request, I see this is posted:

> username=&password=&intent=

rather than this:

> username=qacitester&password=qatester&intent=

And causes web app to not authenticate. Do you have any idea why the input values are not transferred to the backing state (model?) object of React?

Answer (score 5):

Instagram is using the `linkState` method from ReactLink:

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

The login page links to a `bundles/Login.js` that contains compressed code like this:

```
o.createElement("input", {
    className:"lfFieldInput",
    type:"text",
    name:"username",
    maxLength:30,
    autoCapitalize:!1,
    autoCorrect:!1,
    valueLink:this.linkState("username")
}))
```

If you look at the documentation for ReactLink, this means that the input field value only gets sent back to state when the change event fires on the input fields. However, it's not as simple as just firing the change event on the node in question - I think due to the way that React normalises browser events. The React docs specifically say that onChange in React isn't exactly the same as onChange in the browser for various reasons:

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-differences.html

Fortunately in your case Instagram are using React with Addons included which gives you access to React TestUtils, so you can do:

```
var frm = window.frames[1].document.forms[0];
var fReact = window.frames[1].React;
fReact.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.change(frm.elements[0], {target: {value: 'qacitester' }});
fReact.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.change(frm.elements[1], {target: {value: 'qatester' }});
frm.elements[2].click();
```

More documentation here:

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html

Notice that since the login form itself is in an iframe, you *must* use the instance of React from that iframe otherwise the TestUtils won't be able to find the nodes correctly.

This will *only* work in situations where React Addons are included on the page. The normal non-Addons build of React will require another solution. However, if you're specifically talking about ReactLink then that's an addon anyway, so it's not an issue.

Comment: I have actually used jquery.autotype ( https://github.com/mmonteleone/jquery.autotype ) to populate the inputs but still no dice. http://screencast.com/t/gfhWW4rD3R

Comment: The `change` event will only fire if the field gains then loses focus (blur) *and* the value changed in between. Therefore if you'd doing any automated form-filling that doesn't do focus & blur, it still won't work.

Comment: I have edited my comment with a solution that works without extra libraries.

Comment: ps. this new solution can be cut and paste directly into the Chrome console.

Comment: Thanks Colin, that works. But I need to check what that 'change' function performs behind the scenes apart from simply setting values. I need to decompose that part as a generic JS code. I don't want to include React specific object references in my solution.

Comment: If you don't end up using the React TestUtils I suspect you'll end up writing code that looks a lot like it. There's all sorts of code to run simulations of browser events and other kind of labyrinthine stuff. If you do want to go that route you'll have more luck on the react mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/reactjs) than here I think.

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question, the required event is **input** event it seems and this code works:

```
var doc = window.frames[1].document;
var frm = doc.forms[0];
frm.elements[0].value = 'qacitester';
var evt = doc.createEvent('UIEvent');
evt.initUIEvent('input', true, false);
frm.elements[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
frm.elements[1].value = 'qatester';
frm.elements[1].dispatchEvent(evt);
frm.elements[2].click();
```

Answer (score 1):

The login form is actually inside an iFrame, which makes things a wee bit more complicated. I was able to successfully submit a login running the following code *from the chrome console*. I'm using React's TestUtils, but you may be fine with AutoType:

```
// run in Chrome console
var frame = document.querySelector('iframe[src*="login"]');
var s = document.createElement('script');
var username = frame.contentDocument.querySelector('input[name="username"]');
var password = frame.contentDocument.querySelector('input[name="password"]');
s.src = "https://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.0.js";
frame.contentDocument.body.appendChild(s);

// wait for the script request to resolve and use:
change = frame.contentWindow.React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.change;
change(username, {target: {value: 'My Great Username'}});
change(password, {target: {value: 'securepassword'}});
```

**Background**

React uses its own virtual event system, and typically uses [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), which essentially means the input `value` is set by react and trickles down to DOM element.

With that in mind, I believe the issue you are experiencing is because react looks for a key event on the input, and uses the value of the input at the time of the event to set the value of the DOM element. Since you are just setting the `value` property of the DOM element, you are breaking out of the controlled component cycle.

I did a quick spike attempting to dispatch a `KeyboardEvent` on the input, but it was, alas, unsuccessful. I'll update my answer if indeed I do succeed.

**Non satisfactory workaround:**

Use casper/phantomjs to automate form filling. This means you don't have to worry about dispatching events yourself and you can just let the "browser" do it for you. It's also better than working in the console manually.

Comment: As I have commented on the other answer, I have used jquery.autotype which practically fires all the necessary events and tries to simulate the behavior of user typing the letters but I still cannot make it work. I need to solve this issue in JS context as I am automating a 3rd party chrome-wrapper which I can only control via JS code.

Comment: @huseyint so it appears that the form is in an iFrame. I've updated my code with a very hacky hack that I was able to successfully submit the form with; it probably won't accomplish what you want to do programatically, but it's a start :)

Comment: lol, thanks for the effort but I am looking for a pure-JS solution :)